# Unable to find error in my Knapsack Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

My Algorithm looks exactly the same when comparing with other online sources but I can't find the error.

```
int knapSack(int value[],int weight[],int size,int W)
{
    int knapsack[size+1][W+1];

    for(int i = 0;i<=size;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<=W;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
             knapsack[i][j] = 0;

                if(weight[i-1] > j)
                 knapsack[i][j] = knapsack[i-1][j];
                else
                 knapsack[i][j] = max(knapsack[i-1][j],value[i-1]+knapsack[i-1][W-weight[i-1]]);

        }
    }

    return knapsack[size][W];
}
```

Comment: `int knapsack[n+1][W+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  That's the first error.  *My Algorithm looks exactly the same when comparing with other online sources* -- That's the second error -- taking code you don't know, and doing an eye comparison thinking that it should work.  Why not understand and debug the code to see why it doesn't work?

Comment: Also, it makes more sense to use meaningful variable names, not one-letter names like `w` and `W`.  It makes the code more readable and understandable.  Second `if(w[i-1] > j)` -- what happens if `i == 0`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion but it would be helpful if you could point out the error.

Comment: Add any case for which your code gives wrong result and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

When `i==0 || j==0` then you don't need to calculate anything, its result is always `0`.
Currently, it goes into the if-else and calculates it again for this case.

```
if(i==0 || j==0){
   knapsack[i][j] = 0;
   continue;
}
```

Comment: @MurmuDev  did you try this solution ?